# how to add multiselect dropdown in a form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, choice-field

I want multiple selectable dropdown instead of checkboxes. 
[image]

Please help

Comment: not tested, just googled: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/dropdown-list-with-multiple-selection-option-in-sharepoint-2/

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not available as out of the box (**you need to customize it with visual web part or InfoPath form**)

Regarding switching from check box to drop down

- Go to List Settings > In the column settings > Select drop down instead check box

[image]

Comment: I think he want to have the option to select multiple choices of the dropdown, which is not working with the method you described

Comment: @Patrick are you down vote me ? can I know Why ? :)

Comment: yes i want to have the option to select multiple choices of the dropdown instead of checkboxes.

Comment: @JounMartin, please see my comment on your answer and Akul's comment

Comment: @Patrick but down vote is not the optimum response to all answers , especially I updated the answer, comment is useful, if I not response you can down vote me bro,

Comment: @Akul I tried to help you not for only gaining points , but I wonder Is my answer is not considered useful and related to your question ? !